# Make a struct "range-able"?

Tags: go

```
type Friend struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

type Friends struct {
    friends []Friend
}
```

I'd like to make `Friends` range-able, that means, if I have a variable `my_friends` with type `Friends`, I can loop though it with:

```
for i, friend := range my_friends {
    // bla bla
}
```

is it possible in Go?

Comment: Could you state a real-world use case for this? i.e, why do you want to this instead of `range Friends.friends` or `range Friends.List()` (example only)?

Comment: Example: later you upgrade your list to a list of households (groups of friends) and you don't want to change existing client code that works perfectly fine iterating over individual friends.

Answer (score 14):

Has *Friends* to be a struct? Otherwise simply do

```
type Friends []Friend
```

Comment: I think this is a very good answer.  If `Friends struct` only has the contents shown then define the type as `type Friends []Friend`.  Go can have methods on types like this not just on `struct`s which is a bit different from most languages.

Comment: I might be a bit later for the party, but what if I want to iterate over my own linked list, or my own set implementation?

Answer (score 13):

**Beware**: As [deft_code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894333/make-a-struct-range-able/12896013#comment44634199_12896013) mentions, this code leaks a channel and a goroutine when the loop breaks. Do not use this as a general pattern.

---

In go, there is no way to make an arbitrary type compatible for `range`, as 
`range` only supports slices, arrays, channels and maps.

You can iterate over channels using `range`, which is useful if you want to iterate over dynamically generated data without having to use a slice or array.

For example:

```
func Iter() chan *Friend {
   c := make(chan *Friend)
   go func() {
      for i:=0; i < 10; i++ {
        c <- newFriend()
      }
      close(c)
   }()
   return c
}

func main() {
  // Iterate 
  for friend := range Iter() {
    fmt.Println("A friend:", friend)
  }
}
```

That's the closest thing you can have to make something 'rangeable'.

So a common practice is to define a method `Iter()` or something similar on your type and
pass it to `range`.

See [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) for further reading on `range`.

Comment: The downside of course is that using channels here is not efficient compared to ranging over slices. Each channel read/write could cause the runtime to switch to a different goroutine, when in most cases you could range over a slice without being preempted by other goroutines.

Comment: This is true until constructing the slice is prohibitively expensive or otherwise undesirable.  For example, in [cbfs](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/cbfs) I sometimes traverse all files (or files within a range).  There can be billions of them and it requires batched requests against the database and fun stuff like that.

Comment: This leaks a channel and a goroutine if the range isn't iterated to completion. Simple solution to the leak cause races or dead locks. A complete robust solution is very complex and subtle. The consensus on Google's internal Go mailing list is that this is an antipattern.

Comment: @deft_code You are right, this code leaks. I added a warning not to use this as a general pattern, although I like it.